# Datetime update is one day off

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, client-object-model

I'm updating a list with a date field (just the date) using the ECMASCRIPT object model but when the date is inserted is one day off from the introduced date, It's literally making me pull my hair off here's my code:

```
var fecv = new Date(fecvstring);
fecv = fecv.toISOString();
oListItem.set_item('date', fecv);
oListItem.update();
context.load(oListItem);
context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function(){onLotCExt(oListItem);}), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onLotCFail));
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Dates off by one day - what could possibly be the cause? Time zones perhaps?

Answer (score 4):

SharePoint expects the dates sent back to it via the Client Object Model to be in [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (aka GMT) time zone.

If you have a date of

2012-08-21 00:00 in New York (which is 4 hours AHEAD of UTC) that =

2012-08-**20** 18:00 so appears as 'yesterday'

[Convert your date/times to UTC before sending to the server.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj246758%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

In sp.js

```
SP.TimeZone.localTimeToUTC()
```

Comment: how do I use that method? the documentation says practically nothing, suppose I have a Date object, how do I convert it with that method?

Comment: var isoDate = SP.TimeZone.localTimeToUTC(fecv).toString();
oListItem.set_item('date', isoDate);

Comment: For those using Moment.js, it is `moment(dateValue).utc().toJSON();`

Answer (score 1):

Example: update ListItem datetime field "dateField" (only for SharePoint 2013)

```
var addBrowserUtcOffset = function (date) {
    var utcOffsetMinutes = date.getTimezoneOffset();
    var newDate = new Date(date.getTime());
    newDate.setTime(newDate.getTime() - (utcOffsetMinutes*60*1000));

    return newDate;
}


function updateListItem() {
    this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    var date = new Date(2012, 8, 17, 5, 0);
    console.log(date);
    this.isoDate = clientContext.get_web().get_regionalSettings().get_timeZone().localTimeToUTC(date.toISOString());

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onGetDate),
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );
}

function onGetDate() {
    var dateToInsert = addBrowserUtcOffset(this.isoDate.get_value());

    var oList = this.clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('testlist');
    var oListItem = oList.getItemById(1);
    oListItem.set_item('dateField', dateToInsert.toISOString());
    oListItem.update();

    this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onUpdate),
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );
}

function onUpdate() {
    console.log('DONE');
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

updateListItem();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var dateToStart = new Date(yourlocaldate).toISOString();
```

Comment: Would you please explain your answer, just code will not help the readers.